# jQuery UI dialog box appears at top of page while page is loading

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a jQuery dialog box on my website.  I give a div on the page the "dialog" id it's contents become the contents of the dialog box.  However, when the page is loading, this div appears at the top of the page and looks bad.  Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just hide your div via your CSS file:

```
#dialog {display: none}
```

This will not affect its actual display when the dialog is opened.

*I tested to be sure, and this method worked with jQuery UI 1.7.2*

Comment: Wow, that worked beautifully.  Why doesn't this cause the contents of the dialog box to be hidden when it pops up?

Comment: Because that's all jQuery is doing to show or hide it...   it's just toggling the display style.

Comment: Your `div` actually gets nested into the markup for the `ui` dialog. It would remain hidden except that during setup, the `ui` library calls `.show()` on the div which overrides the CSS. It is on line 71 of `ui.dialog.js` in the uncompressed source if you are interested :)

Comment: @Brian: jQuery adds an inline style to the box. Inline styles have precedence over all other styles (except for `!important` declarations).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the dialog is changing the 'display' style [eg using .show() and .hide()] then all jQueryUI is doing is setting the display style.  thus, you can set the div with the `display:none` by default, and that way it won't show when you load.